# I am trying to run my WAS server from Eclipse and I have some permission problems with my WAS profile. How can I solve it?

Tags: eclipse, server, websphere

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6guQE.png)

I am trying to send my first message to a queue in WAS that I created. So, I need to run my WAS server from Eclipse. Is there any way to give permission to myself to use "Custom01" profile and solve this error?

Note: I don't want to create another profile. But if there is no other way it is okay.

I checked the port numbers in eclipse and WAS admin console, I don't think problem result from there.

Comment: Permission from OS. Perhaps you created the profile as root/admin and try to use it as a regular user.

Comment: please post exactly what "some permission problems" means.  operating system errs, log messages, etc.

Comment: Almost seems like it belongs on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Yes it is I think. I did not know this site, I will ask my question over there. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is the exact error that I linked as image in the question with "Error Message".